# codeigniter method parametre get wrong value after add a langue abreviation to uri

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

After I added the abriviation of the language to the link the method on the wrong parameter ex:

in the normal case:

localhost/mysite/method/parameter1/parameter2

```
Public function method($val1, $val2) {
echo $val1;
echo $val2;
}
```

return:
// parametre1
// parametre2

After adding language:
localhost/mysite/en/method/parameter1/parameter2

```
Public function method($val1, $val2){
echo $val1;
echo $val2;
}
```

return:
// method
// parametre1

someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you want to change how Codeigniter read URLs, you can change or add them in config/routes.php

You can refer to Codeigniter's Routing doucumentation - https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Example:

```
$route['method/en/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'method/$1/$2';
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but even with the modification of the route it returns the same thing

$ Route ['^ fr /(.+)$'] = "$ 1";
$ Route ['^ ar /(.+)$'] = "$ 1";
// '/ en' and '/ ar' -> use default controller
$ Route ['^ (fr | ar) $'] = $ route ['default_controller'];

$ route ['^ (fr | ar) / method'] = 'home / methods';
$ route ['^ (fr | ar) / method / (: any) $'] = 'home / methods / $ 1';
$ route ['^ (fr | ar) / method / (: any) / (: any) $'] = 'home / methods / $ 1 / $ 2';

Comment: the use of ^ - means the **very start** of the URL. You might want to make it `$route[(fr|ar)/method/(:any)/(:any)$] = 'home/methods/$2/$3';` and make sure url_rewrite is enabled on your PHP config